# Wordpress htaccess - I want to redirect all 404 Pages To Homepage with the exception of wp-admin and one more URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I need to redirect all my 404 pages to the homepage with the exception of wp-admin and one more URL using htaccess.

I tried some codes but it didn't work for me.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't do this "using htaccess" - since only WordPress knows what should be a 404 or not. "with the exception of wp-admin and one more URL" - But these are presumably non-404 responses anyway?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below code, by putting in your Htaccess file -

Note: Replace "/index.html" with your home page URL or Page.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```